# Why can't I use integers as an index in a PHP $_SESSION array?

Tags: php

Eg:

```
$_SESSION['1'] = 'username'; // works
$_SESSION[1] = 'username'; //doesnt work
```

I want to store session array index as array index. So that o/p is :

```
Array(
[1] => 'username'
)
```

Comment: It's legacy of register_globals stuff. Anyway, having such items in the session is a nonsense. Nested array **is** a way to go.

Comment: The ability to increment the session variable would have been useful because it's an easy way to store information about each previous request without overwriting. The way I worked around this limitation was the way @KenBoyer did below, by prepending some uniform string to the numeric value. It's a little bit of a hassle with some computational overhead.

Answer (score 9):

`$_SESSION` can only be used as an associative array.

You could do something like this though:

```
$_SESSION['normal_array'] = array();
$_SESSION['normal_array'][0] = 'index 0';
$_SESSION['normal_array'][1] = 'index 1';
```

Personally, I'd just stick with the associative array.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'someuser';
```

Or

```
$_SESSION['username_id'] = 23;
```

Comment: gd logic. AS session accepts only associative so storing under same array index & then under that to store inteeger values as array index

Answer (score 7):

I suspect this is probably because the $_SESSION array is purely an associative array. Additionally, as the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) puts it:

> The keys in the $_SESSION associative
>   array are subject to the same
>   limitations as regular variable names
>   in PHP, i.e. they cannot start with a
>   number and must start with a letter or
>   underscore.

Incidentally, have you checked your error log for any NOTICE level errors? (You may have to enable this level.) Attempting to use a numeric key will quite possibly raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take this approach to save an array dimension:

```
$_SESSION['form_'.$form_id] = $form_name;
```

which might look like the following:

```
$_SESSION['form_21'] = 'Patient Evaluation';
```

as opposed to:

```
$_SESSION['form'][21] = 'Patient Evaluation';
```

which uses another array dimension.

Comment: Yes but the first dimension must be associative